# How do I change the color vibrance/saturation with Intel graphics on my laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, colors, lenovo-laptop

The nVidia control panel has an option to adjust the saturation and other properties of the image shown on the screen. Is there any way to do this with the Intel Graphics driver? My laptop model is a Lenovo u350.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using windows the best your gonna get is the Intel Graphics control panel. Look in the control panel and you'll find something like 'Intel GMA Driver' then click the 'Color Correction' tab.

Answer (score 0):

At least in newer cards, there's a new control panel too. If that's the case then the options you need to find to change you color saturation are the following:

- Run the Intel(R) Control Panel (look it up in start menu search, it's faster);
- Select "Display" in the left panel;
- Select "Color enhancement" inside "Display", still in the left panel;
- Adjust the saturation there and other color options.

Be aware that if you connect your monitor through HDMI there won't be any option to adjust saturation or hue. There's a question about this issue, which is real and really unconfortable with some monitors, like the LG M2250D which on Windows will get an extreme saturation level, by default (using HDMI only).

The question is: [Intel Graphics saturation setting disappears when using HDMI](https://superuser.com/questions/423786/intel-graphics-saturation-setting-disappears-when-using-hdmi)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy, just follow these steps (hit the tray icon for Intel graphics first):

```
Intel Graphic Preferences -> Display devices -> Color -> Advanced
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color vibrance/saturation with Intel graphics on your laptop, follow these steps:

- Right-click on your desktop and select "Graphics Properties" or "Graphic Options."
- Look for the "Color" or "Display" settings in the graphics control panel.
- Adjust the "Saturation" or "Vibrance" slider to increase or decrease the color intensity.
- Apply the changes and exit the graphics control panel.

**Note:** The specific steps may vary slightly depending on your Intel graphics driver version and laptop model.