# Intel Graphics saturation setting disappears when using HDMI

Tags: hdmi, lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics, display-settings

I have a little problem.

You see the **Saturation** setting in Color Enhancement is there when you're using the laptop alone, but as soon as I plug in HDMI to a display, that particular setting disappears and I'm only left with Brightness, Contrast & Gamma.

Anyone has any idea why does this happen?

- **Laptop** : Lenovo IdeaPad U400
- **Display** : Samsung HDTV T27A550
- **Graphics** : Intel HD Graphics ( 3000 I think ) with AMD Radeon HD 6470M, switchable graphics.

Comment: I tried a different HDMI cable, the same thing.

Comment: I tried another Samsung HDTV, no difference.

Comment: All drivers are installed ( I think ), I tried updating, everything is up to date.

Comment: Samsung HDTV's color setting is disabled, since I am on HDMI PC mode, so I can't use that.